# Internet and apt-get very slow

Tags: wireless, 13.10, apt, xubuntu

I am using xubuntu `13.10` right now and I have some Internet problems.
When I use `apt-get` it takes almost forever to download just a few kBytes.
I get results like these and it pauses there for a long time:

```
jens@Ultrabuch:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for jens: 
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy InRelease
Holen: 1 http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy Release.gpg [72 B]                     
OK   http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy Release                                    
OK   http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Sources                               
OK   http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main amd64 Packages                        
OK   http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-de_DE                      
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-de                         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en                         
Ign http://archive.canonical.com saucy InRelease                               
OK   http://archive.canonical.com saucy Release.gpg                            
OK   http://archive.canonical.com saucy Release                 
OK   http://archive.canonical.com saucy/partner amd64 Packages                 
OK   http://archive.canonical.com saucy/partner i386 Packages   
Ign http://archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Translation-de_DE
Ign http://archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Translation-de   
Ign http://archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Translation-en   
96% [Verbindung mit archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1360:8c01::18)
```

It appears to me that these freezes are caused by "Translation" packages, they are always ignored.
I tried to change the server as well, that didn't work either, as can be seen below.

When I reload `synaptic` I get this message:

> Could not download all repository indexes
>
> The repository may no longer be available or could not be contacted because of         network problems. If available, an older version of the failed index will be used. Otherwise, the repository will be ignored. Check your network connection and ensure the repository address is correct in 'Repositories' under 'Settings'.
>
> Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/InRelease
> Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I'd be very happy if someone could help me with that!

Best regards,
Jens

Output of `ifconfig -a`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 50:b7:c3:07:35:1e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
          inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:2440 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:2440 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
          RX-Bytes:211909 (211.9 KB)  TX-Bytes:211909 (211.9 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse c8:f7:33:11:38:70  
          inet Adresse:192.168.2.105  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::caf7:33ff:fe11:3870/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          inet6-Adresse: 2003:66:8807:c620:456b:7fc9:1041:7cc9/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Global
          inet6-Adresse: 2003:66:8807:c620:caf7:33ff:fe11:3870/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:28809 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:18907 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:32338097 (32.3 MB)  TX-Bytes:3088377 (3.0 MB)
```

Partial output of `apt-fast`:

```
Hit http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de saucy-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de saucy-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de saucy-backports/main Translation-en_GB     
Ign http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de saucy-backports/main Translation-de        
Ign http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de saucy-backports/multiverse Translation-en_GB
Ign http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de saucy-backports/multiverse Translation-de
Ign http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de saucy-backports/restricted Translation-en_GB
Ign http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de saucy-backports/restricted Translation-de
Ign http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de saucy-backports/universe Translation-en_GB
Ign http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de saucy-backports/universe Translation-de
Ign http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de saucy-security/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de saucy-security/main Translation-de
Ign http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de saucy-security/multiverse Translation-en_GB
Ign http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de saucy-security/multiverse Translation-de
Ign http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de saucy-security/restricted Translation-en_GB
Ign http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de saucy-security/restricted Translation-de
Ign http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de saucy-security/universe Translation-en_GB
Ign http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de saucy-security/universe Translation-de
98% [Connecting to archive.canonical.com (2001:67c:1360:8c01::16)]>
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `ifconfig -a` to your question?

Comment: Where are you from and which is your provider? 'cause I have similar issues with Kable Deutschland.

Comment: I am from Germany and I use Deutsche Telekom. I had DSL 16 with a different router before and I didn't have these problems with xubuntu.

Comment: Sure that DT has no disruption in your area?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Downloads are constantly fast. `apt-get` freezes every time I have tried so far.

Comment: Close voters: This question is not EOL as 13.10 was supported at the time it was asked. I am, however, closing it because the OP hasn't been seen since March and it appears to be a rather localized issue.

Answer (score 1):

Apt-fast is a script that can "drastically improve APT download speed" by using command line download accelerators such as Axel or Aria2 with multiple connections per package.

Ubuntu users can install the latest stable `apt-fast` from its official PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apt-fast/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-fast
```

`apt-fast` configuration:

When installing apt-fast in Ubuntu via its PPA, the package asks you if you want to use aptitude or apt-get, what download manager to use (axel or aria2c). If, later on, you want to change some of the apt-fast options, use the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure apt-fast
```

aria2c is the download tool recommended by the apt-fast developers, mostly because it supports resuming downloads.

### Using apt-fast:

apt-fast works the same as apt-get and all you have to do is use "sudo apt-fast install PACKAGE" instead of "apt-get" and so on for any operation.

Install a package:

```
sudo apt-fast install PACKAGE
```

Upgrade packages:

```
sudo apt-fast upgrade
```

Install the build dependencies for a package:

```
sudo apt-fast build-dep PACKAGE
```

Like I was saying, the commands are identical to apt-get and all you have to do is replace "apt-get" with ["apt-fast"](http://www.unixmen.com/improve-apt-get-download-speed-apt-fast/). There's also a download command ("apt-fast download PACKAGE") which downloads the binary into the current directory.

Comment: Thanks for your help! As I noticed earlier I haven't had this problem before, `apt-get` always ran pretty fast even though I had a slower Internet connection. I am not a pro but I can imagine that the problem lies in the connection to some servers or wifi settings maybe.

Comment: Is the connection slow down only when using apt-get or software center?

Comment: Yes, I think so!

Comment: Does apt-fast have the same problem as apt-get ?

Comment: Yeah, `apt-fast` doesn't work for me. I've updated the question to post the output of that.

Answer (score 0):

First: `Ign` is ok - it means that repo has not changed since last check and no indexes need to be downloaded.

It seems you accessing ubuntu repo through ipv6, have you noticed any problems with other ipv6 enabled hosts?

You may use `ping6` or `traceroute6` for quick check of latency and packets loss (although you should remember that TCP and ICMP traffic may be treated differently by your ISP or intermediate hosts), i.e.

```
ping6 -c20 -i0.5 archive.canonical.com
```

Packets loss or high time indicates that you have some network problems.

Try to compare it to ICMP via ipv4:

```
ping -c20 -i0.5 archive.canonical.com
```

If problem seems to be network-related, try to get rid of ipv6 and check if it helps. You may just delete ipv6 address from your network interface (with DHCP it will be reassigned after reconnect, so it's safe to do so):

```
sudo ip addr del 2003:66:8807:c620:456b:7fc9:1041:7cc9/64 dev wlan0
sudo ip addr del 2003:66:8807:c620:caf7:33ff:fe11:3870/64 dev wlan0
```

---

Also you may check how repo works in browser or try to download something using `curl`/`wget` or similar low-level tool (choose single-threaded tool), for example

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/Contents-i386.gz
```

If you'll get much higher download speed with browser/wget than with apt - it may be some problem related to apt.